# ¿Cómo cambiar el tamaño a mi imagen en Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

No puedo cambiar el tamaño de mi imagen que traigo de mi servidor ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

```
  AQuery aq=new AQuery(this); // initialize aquery
  aq.id(R.id.image_view).image(rutaimg);
```

Comment: Es importante especificar usas AQuery. @Naxin

Answer (score 5):

Puedes definir la medida a la cual deseas cambiar tu imagen directamente en el `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
/>
```

Programaticamente puedes usar [LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) para modificar el alto u ancho:

```
int ancho = 120;
int alto = 120;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ancho, alto);
myImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Si deseas usar `match_parent` o `wrap_content` :

```
myImageView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
myImageView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

Comment: se puede poner la altura y ancho y despues por codigo cambiar estos ?

Comment: Mediante setLayoutParams() puedes modificar esas propiedades, agregué lo que comentas a mi respuesta.

Comment: Si el ancho quisiera que sea match parent o wrap etc? se puede o solo pueden ser especificos

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag por ejemplo : myImageView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

Answer (score 2):

Lo ideal sería siempre especificar un tamaño a través del Layout (XML) e intentar evitar hacerlo programáticamente para así evitar tener que lidiar con las diferentes densidades de pantalla.

```
 <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/mi_imagen"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
    />
```

Y lo más importante, cuidado con los px (píxeles) utiliza siempre dp y te ahorrará muchísimos problemas, aquí tienes un artículo: [¿Qué son y para qué sirven los DP en Android?](https://tyris-software.com/que-son-y-para-que-sirven-los-dp-en-android/), que lo explica muy bien.

Espero que te ayude.